# IOS/XCODE: Calling NSFetchedResultsController Method in Other Class

Tags: ios, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an NSFetchedResultsController in a tableview and am trying to call it from another controller but am getting an error.

I imported the tableVC into the otherVC but am getting a "No known class method for selector "fetchedResultsController".  Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

```
code in tableVC.h
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController;
tableVC.m
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController==nil){
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        ...
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
otherVC.m
#import "tableVC.h"

  [tableVC fetchedResultsController];
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No known class method for selector" indicates that you are calling a class method, not an instance method.

Class methods are defined with a leading + sign, and your fetchedResultsController in tableVC.h is defined with a leading - sign, indicating that it is an instance method.

The solution is to either change the method signature of fetchedResultsController in tableVC.h to a class method, or change the call in otherVC.m to use an instance of tableVC rather than the class itself.

Based on your code sample, it looks like the fetchedResultsController method is defined correctly as an instance method, so you need to use an instance of tableVC in the otherVC class.

Comment: Ok.  Doing tableVC *tableVC = nil;
                    [tableVC fetchedResultsController]; seemed to get method to fire so I have marked question right. However, is there a way to set the FRC to nil so that I can get it to reload.  It lazy loads but since it already exists it is not re-fetching.

Comment: In general, if your NSFetchedResultsController is non-tracked (has no delegate assigned), and you are not changing the predicate, and you have not set a cache, then all you need to do is call [fetchedResultsController performFetch] followed by a call to reloadData on your table view [self.tableView reloadData].  

If you are using caching then look at [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:cacheName].

I would also recommend looking into setting a delegate and using tracking so the table view always stays up to date as changes are made to your model.

Comment: A table VC has registered as a delegate and gets updated when you add a new item but for some reason it does not get updated when you edit the item although the save code is identical.  In addition, the detail VC in question does not have a table, just labels and pictures.   I can't get these to refresh.  Understand the value of MVC but maddening that something so trivial is so complex in IOS.

Comment: There are definitely some nuances to getting everything working properly with Core Data backed UITableViews. It would be hard to help with your specific problem without looking at your code. You may find it useful to look at a full example of Core Data with UITableViews such as [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from Apple.

Comment: Perhaps it is a mistake to have a separate modal edit controller.  The example you sent me uses the detail view for editing.  Maybe that's what Apple wants.  It is proving impossible to get the detail view to update from the managed object context without going through the tableview and prepare for segue to the detail first.

Comment: When you say the detail view is not refreshing, are you talking about it showing the correct detailed information as you tap on separate table view items?